# Comparing patients risk of deaths and validation of a survival model

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, validation

I have two questions for you today.

#### First question

Assume I have two patients, each with a fitted survival curve $S_1$ and $S_2$ (cox proportional hazard model) in `R`. One has been *exposed* for three years, the other for two years. Now I want to compare the risk of death within the next year for each subject for the purposes of ranking.

I have thought of some possible ways to do this, could you please explain if one is correct and why? Also, I would be interested in knowing what each scenario would tell me in any case. If none are correct I would appreciate guidance on what would be the appropriate way:

1. Compare $S_1(3+1)-S_1(3)$ with $S_2(2+1)-S_2(2)$?
2. Compare $S_1(1)$ and $S_2(1)$?
3. Calibrate $S_1$ and $S_2$ now that they have survived 3 and 2 years and then compare $\tilde{S}_1(1)$ and $\tilde{S}_2(1)$? If so how - dividing the curve by $S_1(3)$ and $S_2(2)$?

Essentially I want to order my patients by who is the most likely to die given a time period.

#### Second question

How do I validate my model? Imagine I have data spanning 2010 until today. I could use 2010-2016 for training/fitting and keeping 2017 until today for testing/validation.

But how do I validate with the remaining data then? I imagine ordering by the most likely to die within 2017 until today. Grouping in deciles (or finer) and then comparing with whom actually died. But I am not sure on an explicit measure for this part. Any good suggestions or other approaches?

Comment: Could you more clearly state and signpost your hypothesis for question 1? Do you want to simply quantify the difference in risk of death or do you want to determine if it is statistically significant? Your 3 suggestions answer different questions, would you be interested in having the answerer explain what information each would give? I will propose an edit based on my reading of the question and you can choose to modify it or reject it and update yourself. Also, it would probably be better to ask the two questions separately as they are about quite different aspects.

Comment: Edit approved. I simply want to rank my patients by risk of death - significance are not of interest. Essentially I want to identify who is most likely to die and validate my model performance on historic data.